# Implement Strategy pattern for 1. Print Report. 2. Movie type

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

**I need to know whether I have implemented Strategy pattern correctly** for below 3 classes provided to me for 2 tasks.1) Report Generation 2) Movie Type.
*Below 3 classes were provided to me*

1. Rental.java
2. Movie.java
3. Customer.java

   ```
   public class Rental {
   private Movie _movie;
   private int _daysRented;

   public Rental(Movie movie, int daysRented) {
   _movie = movie;
   _daysRented = daysRented;
   }

   public int getDaysRented() {
   return _daysRented;
      }
      public Movie getMovie() {
   return _movie;
     }
    }
   ```

/* Movie.java */

```
public class Movie {
public static final int CHILDRENS = 2;
public static final int REGULAR = 0;
public static final int NEW_RELEASE = 1;
private String _title;
private int _priceCode;

public Movie(String title, int priceCode) {
    _title = title;
    _priceCode = priceCode;
}

public int getPriceCode() {
    return _priceCode;
}

public void setPriceCode(int arg) {
    _priceCode = arg;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return _title;
};
}
```

/* Customer.java */

```
public class Customer {
private String _name;
private Vector _rentals = new Vector();

public Customer(String name) {
    _name = name;
};

public void addRental(Rental arg) {
    _rentals.addElement(arg);
}

public String getName() {
    return _name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Customer c = new Customer("Chhavi");
    Movie m = new Movie("Jab Tak Hai Jaan", 1);
    Rental r = new Rental(m, 10);
    c.addRental(r);
    // Rental calculation
    String s = c.statement();
    System.out.println("s: " + s);
}

public String statement() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double totalAmount = 0;
    int frequentRenterPoints = 0;
    Enumeration rentals = _rentals.elements();
    String result = "Rental Record for " + getName() + "\n";

    while (rentals.hasMoreElements()) {
        double thisAmount = 0;
        Rental each = (Rental) rentals.nextElement();

        // determine amounts for each line
        switch (each.getMovie().getPriceCode()) {

        case Movie.REGULAR:
            thisAmount += 2;
            if (each.getDaysRented() > 2)
                thisAmount += (each.getDaysRented() - 2) * 1.5;
            break;

        case Movie.NEW_RELEASE:
            thisAmount += each.getDaysRented() * 3;
            break;

        case Movie.CHILDRENS:
            thisAmount += 1.5;
            if (each.getDaysRented() > 3)
                thisAmount += (each.getDaysRented() - 3) * 1.5;
            break;
        } // add frequent
            // renter points
        frequentRenterPoints++;

        // add bonus for a two day new release rental
        if ((each.getMovie().getPriceCode() == Movie.NEW_RELEASE) && each.getDaysRented() > 1)
            frequentRenterPoints++;

        // show figures for this rental
        result += "\t" + each.getMovie().getTitle() + "\t" + String.valueOf(thisAmount) + "\n";
        totalAmount += thisAmount;
    }

    // add footer lines
    result += "Amount owed is " + String.valueOf(totalAmount) + "\n";
    result += "You earned " + String.valueOf(frequentRenterPoints) + " frequent renter points";
    return result;
}
}
```

I have modified above classes to below.

1. Customer.java
2. MovieType.java

   a) MovieTypeInterface.java

   b) Movie.java

   c) Childrens.java

   d) NewRelease.java

   e) Regular.java
3. Rental.java
4. RentalCalculationStrategyInterface.java
5. MainClass.java

/* Customer class */

```
public class Customer {
private String name;
private List<Rental> rentals = new ArrayList<Rental>();

public Customer(String name, List<Rental> list) {
    this.name = name;
    rentals.addAll(list);
}
// getters and setters for class variables
}
```

2. MovieType and its child classes implementation:

   ```
    public interface MovieTypeInterface {
    Movie getMovieType(Movie movie, int movieEnum);
    }
        public class MovieType implements MovieTypeInterface {
        public Movie getMovieType(Movie movie, int movieEnum) {

        Movie m = null;
        if (movieEnum == Constants.CHILDRENS) {
            m = new Childrens(movie.getTitle(), movie.getPriceCode());
        }
    if (movieEnum == Constants.REGULAR) {
        m = new Regular(movie.getTitle(), movie.getPriceCode());
    }
    if (movieEnum == Constants.NEW_RELEASE) {
        m = new NewRelease(movie.getTitle(), movie.getPriceCode());
    }
    return m;
    }
        // @Override
            public Movie getMovie(Movie movie, int moviePriceCode) {
            return new MovieType().getMovieType(movie, moviePriceCode);
            }
            }

    public class Childrens extends Movie {
        public Childrens(String title, int priceCode) {
    super(title, priceCode);
    }
    @Override
        public Map<Double, Integer> getPoints(int daysRented) {
        thisAmount += 1.5;
        if (daysRented > 3)
            thisAmount += (daysRented - 3) * 1.5;
        frequentRenterPoints++;
        map.put(thisAmount, frequentRenterPoints);
        return map;
    }
    }
    public class NewRelease extends Movie {
    public NewRelease(String title, int priceCode) {
    super(title, priceCode);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public Map<Double, Integer> getPoints(int daysRented) {
        thisAmount += daysRented * 3;
    frequentRenterPoints++;
    // HashMap<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
    if (daysRented > 1)
        frequentRenterPoints++;
    map.put(thisAmount, frequentRenterPoints);
    return map;
    }
    }
    public class Regular extends Movie {
        public Regular(String title, int priceCode) {
    super(title, priceCode);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
        @Override
    public Map<Double, Integer> getPoints(int daysRented) {
        thisAmount += 2;
        if (daysRented > 2)
        thisAmount += (daysRented - 2) * 1.5;
        frequentRenterPoints++;
        map.put(thisAmount, frequentRenterPoints);
        return map;
    }
    }
    public class Movie {
    protected double thisAmount = 0;
    protected int frequentRenterPoints;
    private String _title;
    private int _priceCode;
    protected Map<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();

    public Map<Double, Integer> getPoints(int daysRented) {
        this.thisAmount = 0;
            frequentRenterPoints = 0;
            map.put(thisAmount, frequentRenterPoints);
        return map;
    }
    private MovieType movieType;
        public Movie(String title, int priceCode) {
        _title = title;
        _priceCode = priceCode;
    }
    public int getPriceCode() {
        return _priceCode;
    }
    public void setPriceCode(int arg) {
        _priceCode = arg;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return _title;
    }
        public MovieType getMovieType() {
    return movieType;
    }
        public void setMovieType(MovieType movieType) {
        //movieType.getMovieType(this._priceCode);
        this.movieType = movieType;
    }
    }
   ```

/* Rental.java */

```
    public class Rental {
    private Movie _movie;
    private int _daysRented;
        public Rental(Movie movie, int daysRented) {
        _movie = movie;
        _daysRented = daysRented;
    }
        public int getDaysRented() {
        return _daysRented;
    }
        public Movie getMovie() {
        return _movie;
    }
    }
```

/* RentalCalculationStrategyInterface.java  */

```
public interface RentalCalculationStrategyInterface {
    public String statement();
}
```

/* RentalCalculationClass.java */

```
public class RentalCalculationClass implements RentalCalculationStrategyInterface {
    double totalAmount = 0;
    int frequentRenterPoints = 0;
    String title = "";
        private Movie movie;
    private Customer customer;
        public Movie getMovie() {
    return movie;
}

public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}
@Override
public String statement() {
    List<Rental> _rentals = this.getCustomer().get_rentals();
    MovieType movieType = new MovieType();
    Iterator<Rental> rentals = _rentals.iterator();// .elements();
    String result = "Rental Record for " + this.getCustomer().getName() + "\n";

    while (rentals.hasNext()) {
        Rental each = (Rental) rentals.next();
        title = each.getMovie().getTitle();
        Movie movie = movieType.getMovie(each.getMovie(), each.getMovie().getPriceCode());
        Map<Double, Integer> mape = movie.getPoints(each.getDaysRented());
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Integer> map : mape.entrySet()) {
            totalAmount = map.getKey();
            frequentRenterPoints = map.getValue();
        }
    }
    result += "\t" + title + "\t" + title + "\n";
    // add footer lines
    result += "Amount owed is " + String.valueOf(totalAmount) + "\n";
    result += "You earned " + String.valueOf(frequentRenterPoints) + " frequent renter points. ";
    return result;
}
}
```

/* ReportInterface.java */

```
public interface ReportInterface {
    public void printReport(String data);
}
```

/* ReportHTML.java */

```
    public class ReportHTML implements ReportInterface
    {
    @Override
    public void printReport(String data) {
        System.out.println("Html Report with data="+data);  
    }
}
```

/* ReportPDF.java */

```
    public class ReportPDF implements ReportInterface {
    @Override
    public void printReport(String data) {
        System.out.println("PDF Report with data=" + data);
    }
}
```

/* Finally the main class to test the program */

```
    public class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            RentalCalculationClass rent = new RentalCalculationClass();
        insertData(rent);
        // Rental calculation
        String s = rent.statement();
    System.out.println("s: " + s);

    // Report generation
    ReportInterface ir = new ReportHTML();
    ir.printReport(s);
    
    /* If we want to generate PDF report then we can call PDF Report class*/
    /*ir = new ReportPDF();
    ir.printReport(s);*/
}

/* Insert data into class before testing the problem statement */
private static void insertData(RentalCalculationClass rent) {

    Movie movie1 = new Movie("ABC", 1);
    List<Rental> list = new ArrayList<Rental>();
    Rental rental = new Rental(movie1, 10);
    list.add(rental);

    Customer customer1 = new Customer("ABC", list);
    rent.setCustomer(customer1);
    rent.setMovie(movie1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code and classes, you should provide additional information so that wen can easier digest all that and now how it interacts...and more important, what it does and how they interact with each other.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  The current question title is a bit vague. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples, and revise the title and description accordingly.

Comment: Without a description of what the code is trying to do it is very difficult to provide good answers. The title and the first paragraph of the question should provide this information. Please read the link provided by @Edward.

Comment: Okay. I will add more details. However the only details provided to me were the 3 files and to implement strategy pattern for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The Report Generation has been done with the Strategy pattern.

The Movie Type probably has not. Why probably? Strategy pattern is about behavior, about doing something, a verb, like running, like reporting, like calculating. Movie Type is a classification, a way to organize, to group. In this case Movies.

The Rental Calculation looks like the Strategy pattern.

It doesn't look like the strategies are being used though. Strategy pattern allows behavior to be swapped in or out. For example, a Rental Calculator using different Rental Calculation strategies based on a collection of different Movie Types; each Movie Type being calculated differently with it's own Calculation strategy. Not seeing that anywhere and it's what you should implement next.

Hope that helps. Happy coding.